# Validations with Active Admin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, activeadmin

I have two models, Event and Image:

```
class Event < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :images
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :images

  validates :date, presence: true
  validates :location, presence: true
  validates :name, presence: true
end


class Image < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :event

  mount_uploader :file, AvatarUploader

  validates :file, presence: true
  validates :event, presence: true
end
```

Here are my migrations:

```
class CreateEvents < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :events do |t|
      t.date :date
      t.string :location
      t.string :name

      t.timestamps
  end
 end
end


class CreateImages < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :images do |t|
      t.string :file
      t.string :caption
      t.boolean :featured_image
      t.integer :event_id

      t.timestamps
  end
 end
end
```

I am using Carrierwave to upload the Image. I have no problem getting this feature to work when no validations are built in, but I'm trying to prevent an image being uploaded with it's event_id not being assigned.

Currently, my ActiveAdmin file looks like this:

```
ActiveAdmin.register Event do
  menu label: "Events"

  permit_params :date, :location, :name, images_attributes: [:id, :file, :caption, :featured_image, :event_id]

  form :html => { :enctype => "multipart/form-data" } do |f|
    f.inputs "Event Details" do
      f.input :name
      f.input :location
      f.input :date, :start_year => 2000, :end_year => 2020

    f.inputs "Images" do
      f.has_many :images, :allow_destroy => true, :heading => false, :new_record => true, :html => { :multipart => true } do |p|
        p.input :event_id, :value => f.object.id
        p.input :file, :as => :file
        p.input :caption
        p.input :featured_image
      end
     end  
    end

  f.actions
end
```

The main line in question is where I am assigning the event_id to the value of the object's id (the Event).

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
p.input :event_id, :value => f.object.id
```

to

```
p.input :event_id, input_html: { value: f.object.id }
```

and you're all set

Comment: Genius! Thanks Andrey. Worked great!